# XSLT Count using variable and for-each

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I am trying to get the count using the for-each and counter variable but I am getting an incorrect values. Any help with this would be great.

XML

```
<ProjectFileManagers>
    <ProjectFileManagers>
      <ProjectFileManagerId>34</ProjectFileManagerId>
      <ProjectId>39352</ProjectId>
      <FileManagerId>11</FileManagerId>
    </ProjectFileManagers>
    <ProjectFileManagers>
      <ProjectFileManagerId>35</ProjectFileManagerId>
      <ProjectId>39352</ProjectId>
      <FileManagerId>12</FileManagerId>
    </ProjectFileManagers>
  </ProjectFileManagers>
```

XSLT

```
<tr>
  <td colspan="5">
    <span class="title">
      <xsl:text>Material Attached</xsl:text>
    </span>
    <br />
    <xsl:variable name="materialCount" select="0"></xsl:variable>
      <xsl:for-each select="ProjectFileManagers/ProjectFileManagers/ProjectFileManagerId">
            <xsl:value-of select="$materialCount + 1"/>
      </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:value-of select="$materialCount" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: You seem to think that `xsl:for-each` is a loop and that XSLT variables are mutable. Both of these assertions are false.

Comment: Drop the `disable-output-escaping`. (a) there is nothing here that needs escaping anyway, and (b) if there was, you would want it escaped to make your output well-formed. The presence of this attribute is a code smell - it suggests you are programming by trial and error rather than by reading a specification of the language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in stead of

```
<xsl:value-of select="$materialCount + 1"/>
```

use:

```
<xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
```